# Font not found with Pygments' ImageFormatter

Tags: python, pygments

I'm trying Pygments to convert some code into a highlighted image. Here's the Python script:

```
from pygments.lexers import PhpLexer
from pygments.formatters import ImageFormatter
from pygments.filters import CodeTagFilter
from pygments import highlight
code = open("myPhpCode.php").read()
formatter = ImageFormatter()
with open("myPhpCodeAsAnImage.png", "w+") as f:
    f.write(highlight(code, PhpLexer(), formatter))
```

I've tried Python2 and Python3, on MacOs, I have also tried to set ImageFormatter's option "font_name="pathToFont" with the full path of a font I know exists, and I always get the following error :

> pygments.formatters.img.FontNotFound: No usable fonts named: "Menlo"

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error, check paths [mention in here](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/1223).

Verify that you have the `Menlo` font. At this moment `pygments` are only loading `.ttf` files and ignoring `.ttc`.

In my case, Menlo font extension was `.ttc` instead of `.ttf` I just renamed that file and all works.